# Restrict jQuery event handler to only one container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code for clicking on a container:

And here is the code.

```
$('#toggleSubscribe').click(function() {
    $('#subscribe > .toggleSubscribe').toggle();
    $(this).text(function(i,txt) {
        return txt === "Subscribe" ? "Unsubscribe" : "Subscribe";
    }).toggleClass('myClass');
});
```

But after I add more containers with the same ID, it breaks. Is there a way to alter the code and keep the toggle just on my div so the whole script can be used in multiple places?

Here is a link to the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Zmsnd/238/

Comment: switch them to class names instead of id's. You can only have one id per page.

Comment: I have tried that and it does not seem to work

Comment: I think the problem is your html

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
<div class='subscribe'> 
    <div id='divA' class='toggleSubscribe' style="display:none">You are now Subscribed</div> 

    <a href='#' class='toggleSubscribe'>Subscribe</a>
</div>​ 

<div class='subscribe'> <div id='divB' class='toggleSubscribe' style="display:none">You are now Subscribed</div> 
    <a href='#' class='toggleSubscribe'>Subscribe</a>
</div>​
```

and the js

```
$('a.toggleSubscribe').click(function() {
    var mydiv = $(this).parent('div.subscribe');
    $(mydiv).find('div.toggleSubscribe').toggle();
    $(this).text(function(i,txt) {
        return "Subscribe";
    }).toggleClass('myClass');
});
```

Here's a link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r8M8w/9/

Comment: thank you for your expertise. This solution works great

Comment: hi I apologize I see an error and its not working. A closing div tag at the end causes it not to work and I am unable to change the html. Let me know your thoughts.                                 <div class='subscribe'>
   <div id='divB' class='toggleSubscribe'>You are now Subscribed</div>

<a href='#' class='toggleSubscribe'>Subscribe</a></div>​

<div class='subscribe'>
   <div id='divB' class='toggleSubscribe'>You are now Subscribed</div>

<a href='#' class='toggleSubscribe'>Subscribe</a></div>​

Comment: Hello! I've updated the code. There's a display: none for the toggleSubscribe div intially. If you can't add it to the HTML, you can add a property in css: div.toggleSubscribe { display: none; }

Comment: Is it possible to change the code so that we don't reference the .txt and just have the divs toggle like they do?  return txt === "Unsubscribe" ? "Subscribe" : "Unsubscribe";

Comment: you solution worked btw.. I am just looking to enhance it like mentioned above.

Comment: If I understood correctly you just wanted for "Subscribe" to show. I've updated the code: http://jsfiddle.net/r8M8w/11/

Comment: No so the way I was looking to alter this was to show another div that says "unsubscribe" in the html and not have that part controlled by text in the js. I have updated the fiddle to show you..

Comment: so ideally i'd like to remove " return txt === "Unsubscribe" ? "Subscribe" : "Unsubscribe";" and just have the divs toggle.

Comment: Any ideas? I am still stuck

Answer (score 0):

I would clean up your html. If they are in different containers remove the #subscribe from the jquery selector.

```
<div id='subscribe'>
    <a href='#' class='toggleSubscribe'>Subscribe</a>
    <a href='#' class='toggleSubscribe'>Subscribe</a>
</div>

$('#subscribe .toggleSubscribe').click(function() {
    $(this).text(function(i,txt) {
        return txt === "Subscribe" ? "Unsubscribe" : "Subscribe";
    }).toggleClass('myClass');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zmsnd/241/

Comment: this html differs from what I posted so the script does not work for me.

Comment: <div class='subscribe'> <div id='divB' class='toggleSubscribe'>You are now Subscribed</div> <a href='#' class='toggleSubscribe'>Subscribe</a></div>​ <div class='subscribe'> <div id='divB' class='toggleSubscribe'>You are now Subscribed</div> <a href='#' class='toggleSubscribe'>Subscribe</a></div>